# Ionic 4 Animation object

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to animate my `IonModal` enter and leave and There are 
`enterAnimation` and `leaveAnimation` properties that get Animation object.

**I use ionic/react.** So I the Animation import even does not work! This exception came out: `Attempted import error: 'Animation' is not exported from '@ionic/core'.`

The only example I saw with this object is this : 
https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-custom-modal-page-transition-animation-in-ionic/

I just want to change the side that the modal is entering/leaving from, and this code is not so predictable for it.

Some good examples how to use it with react?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic custom modal animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919631/ionic-custom-modal-animation)

Comment: it's not, cause I'm using ionic-react. just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Ionic Native Page Transitions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions) for your application. I believe it will do what you want in terms of **enter** and **leave** animations.The documentation for this is fairly adequate as well.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of animation for modal similar to the first example presented by [joshmorony](https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-custom-modal-page-transition-animation-in-ionic/) using angular in ionic 4/5/6.

**src/app/animations/enter.ts**

```
import { Animation, createAnimation } from '@ionic/angular';

export const modalEnterAnimation = (
    baseEl: HTMLElement,
    presentingEl?: HTMLElement,
  ): Animation => {

  const backdropAnimation = createAnimation()
    .addElement(baseEl.querySelector('ion-backdrop')!)
    // .fromTo('opacity', 0.01, 'var(--backdrop-opacity)')
    .beforeStyles({
      'pointer-events': 'none'
    })
    .afterClearStyles(['pointer-events']);

  const wrapperAnimation = createAnimation()
    .addElement(baseEl.querySelectorAll('.modal-wrapper, .modal-shadow')!)
    .beforeStyles({ 'opacity': 1 })
    .keyframes([
        { offset: 0, transform: 'translateX(100vh)' },
        { offset: 1, transform: 'translateX(0vh)'},
      ]);

  const baseAnimation = createAnimation()
    .addElement(baseEl)
    .easing('ease-out')
    .duration(300)
    .addAnimation([wrapperAnimation, backdropAnimation]);

  return baseAnimation;

};
```

**src/app/animations/leave.ts**

```
import { Animation, createAnimation } from '@ionic/angular';

export const modalLeaveAnimation = (
    baseEl: HTMLElement,
    presentingEl?: HTMLElement,
  ): Animation => {

  const backdropAnimation = createAnimation()
    .addElement(baseEl.querySelector('ion-backdrop')!)
    // .fromTo('opacity', 0.01, 'var(--backdrop-opacity)')
    .beforeStyles({
      'pointer-events': 'none'
    })
    .afterClearStyles(['pointer-events']);

  const wrapperAnimation = createAnimation()
    .addElement(baseEl.querySelectorAll('.modal-wrapper')!)
    .beforeStyles({ 'opacity': 1 })
    .keyframes([
        { offset: 0, transform: 'translateX(0vh)' },
        { offset: 1, transform: 'translateX(100vh)'},
      ]);

  const baseAnimation = createAnimation()
    .addElement(baseEl)
    .easing('ease-out')
    .duration(300)
    .addAnimation([wrapperAnimation, backdropAnimation]);

  return baseAnimation;
  
};
```